# How to redirect the URL?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite, seo

For SEO, I need to change few URLs like below:

1. My magento site has the same content on these URL's:

   URL 1: `www.example.com/some-product-page/`

   URL 2: `www.example.com/category/subcategory/some-product-page/`

**I need that URL 1 moves to URL 2**.

2. URL: `www.example.com/category/`

   URL: `www.example.com/category/?p=1`
   has the same content, how to fix it?

Comment: Is this to prevent duplicate content issues with google?

Comment: Yes, it is optimization for google.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at implementing Canonical URL's.

This will prevent duplicate content issues with Google.

Yoast offer an extension thats free and can get this done for you.

https://yoast.com/tools/magento/magento-canonical/

Answer (score 1):

You can extend class `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager` with your own module in `catalog.xml` and `catalogsearch.xml` layouts.

**Look for nodes :**

`<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>`

**=> Replace it by**

`<block type="mypage/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>`.

The only method you'll have to change is `getPageUrl` like this :

```
public function getPageUrl($page)
{
    if ($page > 1)
        return $this->getPagerUrl(array($this->getPageVarName()=>$page));
    return $this->getPagerUrl();
}
```

Tell me if it works or if you need more detail :)